# How to get a for loop create a string of 9 random 1digit number?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a random number generator with 9 total digit created from a random 1 digit number generated thru a for loop .

This one works but i need to use a for loop for it :

```
    var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
    var random9 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;



    // ... and then dump the random number into our random-number div.
    $("#random-number").text(""+ random1 + random2 + random3 + random4 + random5 + random6 + random7 + random8 + random9);

    var results = ""+ random1 + random2 + random3 + random4 + random5 + random6 + random7 + random8 + random9 ;
    $("#results").prepend(results + " <br>");
```

the above code works in creating a random 9 digit number but i need to use a for loop to make my code concise .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop. Create a string and in each loop concentrate the new random number with that string.

```js
let random = '';
for(let i =0;i<9;i++){
  random += Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
}
$("#random-number").text(random);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-number"></div>
```

Another way can be using `map()` and `join()`

```js
let random = [...Array(9)].map(x => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1).join('')
$("#random-number").text(random);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-number"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way with all digits is in range [0, 9] and you should relize that first digit can be zero:

```
var digits = [];
for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
        let n = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        digits.push( n );
}
var number = digits.join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a new array where the items are random numbers and then join the array with an empty string.

```js
const random = length => Array.from(Array(length), _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1).join('');

console.log(random(9));
console.log(random(9));
console.log(random(9));
console.log(random(9));
console.log(random(9));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have all the `9` number to be unique you can use a object to keep track of added previously added numbers and if it is not included add a it to random number as well as object

```js
let random = '';
let included = {}
for(let i =0;i<9;i++){
  let temp = true
  while(temp){
   let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 ;
   if(included[num] === undefined){
    temp = false
    random += num
    included[num] = num
   }
  }
}
$("#random-number").text(random);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-number"></div>
```

Comment: This is very bad idea in case of large inputs.even for 1-9.its bad. Iam not downvoter

Comment: @MaheerAli why it is bad ? will you explain

Comment: I would suggest you to create array from 1-9 and get random value out of it and remove it from array. And I downvoter(I didn't noticed it was you). Edit I will remove downvote

Comment: Its bad because it will have many unnecessary while loops. Consider all the numbers are generated except one now it will take more unnecessary while loops to generate that one. And in case of bigger input it may take a lot of time. I hope you got it

Comment: @MaheerAli you need to keep track of previously added values and array will be bad when you need to search frequently, `Map` will still be a better option but before adding random values to `Map` you also need to check all the values are unique

Comment: What is the time-complexity of this in worst case.Can you tell. What I am telling you will have linear time complexity

Comment: I agree with @MaheerAli , the time complexity is bad. If you 'randomly' generate a number and on the first iteration it is 3. Then next iteration it randomly generates a number and gets 3 again, then it says oops its already in the array continue the while loop, this can happen X amounts of times on the second iteration and beyond. If you have an array and remove the randomly generated number then you have no chance of randomly generating the same number the next iteration. Instead of randomly generating a number you would randomly generate the index of the array.

Comment: @MaheerAli in worst case you will endup with infinte loop, but this is not the case here because of `Math.random` which will give a random number in most of case, repitition of previously generated number will be very less

Comment: @CodeManiac I don't mean your code is wrong. But it will not work for bigger inputs. It will give impression to new ones that its correct way to get random numbers without repetition. What I was saying you is this https://jsfiddle.net/maheerali121/y3sLzob7/

Comment: @MaheerAli you have used it in wrong way, with splice you're mutating original arrays length which eventually reduces range of `random` numbers generated by `Math.random`